# how do i read related data on specific user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

**QUESTION**.how can i get the data on **dataorder** under `userId` **vpk1lxv7ZHY7KbOJ4l5Bl4KOBKJ3** and on `idorder` **08-11-karpetyogadwisaputra08213838686868yogadwisaputra1-27** ?

```
FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userid = user.getUid();
        String idorder = idorderrr.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference databaseOrder = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dataorder");
        databaseOrder.child(userid).child(idorder).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String haritanggal = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataOrder.class).getHaritanggalOrder();
                status.setText("jadwal anda= "+haritanggal+" ....."); //<<<id always set null ?????
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
```

I try it like that but data always null. please help

(i got **userid** and **idorder** from **datauser**)

[image]

**UPDATE**
**idorder** output that requested

```
FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userid = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference databaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("datauser");
        databaseUser.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String noma = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataUser.class).getUserName();
                hey.setText("haloo "+noma);
                String idorder = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataUser.class).getUserOrderId();
                idorderrr.setText(idorder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

screnshot output of **idorder** using `addValueListner` on **datauser**

[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ai0I.jpg]

Comment: make sure this is correct `idorder`

Comment: i try make an output 'idorder' on TextView and it's correct sir

Comment: Can you log the values of `idorder` right before you call `addValueEventListener`, and then copy/paste the output into your question?

Comment: UPDATED with output of `idorder` like requested and it is the corect id that's needed. it's me that wrong or there's another way to get the data on **dataorder** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, that's how it works for me

```
 @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataOrder dataorder = dataSnapshot.getValue(dataOrder.class);
            if (dataorder != null) {
            status.setText("jadwal anda= "+ dataorder.haritanggalOrder + "....."); 
        }
```

Comment: btw i tried yours and data comeout, but is this just read the data on user that currently log on and not read the other order data on other iduser ?

Comment: and i tried several time but data just comeout when screen off and turn on again, before that nothing comeout. why it's like that ?

Comment: So you didn't solve the problem that in the first comment yet?
I have an issue to understand the second problem clearly but have you try to reinstall the app or something?

Comment: not yet sir. my problem is just find a way to get the data inside **dataorder** on specific user and in my case it's `userid` that current user log on

Comment: I really want help, so can you please update the question with your current code?

Comment: thank you very much sir, but i think i can just use your suggestion, because it's works for me right now.